# Using Codeigniter's 2.x Pagination, I receive unexpected links and order and sort not working

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, pagination

I am trying to make my first sortable table using codeigniter 2.x and its pagination class.  Unfortunately, while the page shows 10 results per page, the sort order seems wrong and the links in paginations do not work correctly.

I have a mysql table with country_id and country.  I have 21 entries.  Here is a snapshot of the table:

[image]

As the first step, I invoke the method country_index() which is in my controller called admin.  I call the method with the url http://localhost:8000/admin/country_index/:

```
public function country_index($sort_by = 'country_id', $sort_order='ASC', $offset = 0){

    $this->load->model('model_admin');

    $this->load->library('pagination');
    /* This Application Must Be Used With BootStrap 3 *  */
    $config['full_tag_open']    = "<ul class='pagination'>";
    $config['full_tag_close']   ="</ul>";
    $config['num_tag_open']     = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close']    = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open']     = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";
    $config['cur_tag_close']    = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
    $config['next_tag_open']    = "<li>";
    $config['next_tagl_close']  = "</li>";
    $config['prev_tag_open']    = "<li>";
    $config['prev_tagl_close']  = "</li>";
    $config['first_tag_open']   = "<li>";
    $config['first_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
    $config['last_tag_open']    = "<li>";
    $config['last_tagl_close']  = "</li>";
    $config['base_url']         = base_url() . 'admin/country_index/' .$sort_by. '/' .$sort_order;
    $config['total_rows']       = $this->db->get('mhcountry')->num_rows();
    $config['per_page']         = 10; 
    $this->pagination->initialize($config); 
    $data['pagination']         = $this->pagination->create_links(); 
                                // limit, sortby sortorder offset
    $data['query']              = $this->model_admin->search_countries($config['per_page'], $sort_by, $sort_order, $this->uri->segment(5));
    $data['templateVersion']    = 'template1';
    $data['headerVersion']      = 'header1';
    $data['navBarVersion']      = 'navbar1';
    $data['main_content']       = 'detail-wrap/admin/country_index'; 
    $data['page_title' ]        = 'MovingHaus.com - App';
    $data['footerVersion']      = 'footer1';
    $this->load->view('detail-wrap/includes/template1', $data);
}
```

The function country_index() above in turn invokes search_countries() which is located in model_admin.php.  The contents of search_countries() is as follows:

```
    function search_countries($limit , $sort_by = 'country', $sort_order = 'asc', $offset = 0){

    $sort_order = ($sort_order == 'DESC') ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
    $sort_columns = array('country_id', 'country');
    $sort_by = (in_array($sort_by, $sort_columns)) ? $sort_by : 'country';

    $results = $this->db->select('country_id, country')
                ->from('mhcountry')
                ->limit($limit, $offset)
                ->order_by($sort_by, $sort_order)
                ->get()
                ->result();
    return $results;
}
```

The country_index() finally calls my view called country_index.php.  The following is a snipping of the table of the entire code of contry_index.php.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Country ID</th>
                                    <th>Country Name</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th>Options</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                                <?php

                                //var_dump($query);
                                foreach ($query as $row ) {
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row->country_id; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row->country; ?></td>
                                    <td>something</td>
                                    <td>someone</td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <?php echo $pagination; ?>
```

The table is thereafter displayed in my browser per the below.

[image]

I have hovered over the pagination "1" so you are also able to view the corresponding link in the bottom left of the browser.  As expected, when I hover over page 2, page 3 and the 'next page' links in the bottom left of the browser produce the following links respectively which I believe to be correct:

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/country_index/country_id/ASC/10
http://localhost:8000/admin/country_index/country_id/ASC/20
http://localhost:8000/admin/country_index/country_id/ASC/10
```

Unfortunately, after I click the page 2 link, the following is produced.  Please note that the results of country_id and country are correct, however, page 1 is still highlighted. Also, once I am view page 2 results, I am unable to go back to page 1.  Page 3 is viewable and shows the correct results, however, the pagination implies I am on page 1.

[image]

Lastly, when I can the URL to sort in different manners, for example, to view countires is descending order, the results are exactly the same as above. In other words, the results are sorted correctly, however, the pagination bar is working incorrectly in the same manner as above.  For your information, I would use the following URL to view countries in descending order:

http://localhost:8000/admin/country_index/country/DESC/20

Your advice as to what I may be overlooking would be much appreciated.  If you required any additional information, please let me know and I will edit the post with relevant code, snapshots, etc.

Comment: should simplify question

Answer (score 0):

You are missing

> $this->uri->segment(n);

Comment: Thank you for that hint.  I have the following line which I though would cover it... Sorry, seems I am still not understanding this correctly.     $data['query']              = $this->model_admin->search_countries($config['per_page'], $sort_by, $sort_order, $this->uri->segment(5));

Comment: hmm, this is quite strange.  It does appear the sorting works, however, the pagination is just formatted incorrectly.  Not sure why.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could anyone venture a guess as to why the formatting (see above images) is not working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already have solved this but I think you are missing the uri_segment config. In your case it should be 6.

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 6;

The pagination function automatically determines which segment of your URI contains the page number. If you need something different you can specify it.
```